# How to send lead via API to Getresponse

Tags: php, html, api, list, getresponse

I have a html form where name and email address are getting collected. I try to submit these informations to a GetResponse list using this script:

```
<?php

function mytheme_save_to_getresponse($form)
{

    require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
    $api_key = 'myAPIkey';
    $api_url = 'http://api2.getresponse.com';
    $client = new jsonRPCClient($api_url);
    $result = NULL;

try {
    $result = $client->get_campaigns(
        $api_key,
        array (
            # find by name literally
            'name' => array ( 'EQUALS' => 'testlist' )
        )
    );
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    # check for communication and response errors
    # implement handling if needed
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$campaigns = array_keys($result);
$CAMPAIGN_ID = array_pop($campaigns);

    $subscriberEmail =  $_GET['email'];

try {
    $result = $client->add_contact(
        $api_key,
        array (
            'campaign'  => $CAMPAIGN_ID,
            'name'     =>  $subscriberName,
            'email'     =>  $subscriberEmail,
            'cycle_day' => '0'
                    )
    );
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    # check for communication and response errors
    # implement handling if needed
    die($e->getMessage());
}
}
?>
```

The script doesn't show any errors but GetResponse is not saving the lead to my list. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1):

If u are getting a response as [queued]=>1 then your script is working fine..
It will be added to your contact only after a validation/confirmation of entered email
 $subscriberEmail will recieve a confirmation email...after the user click on the link contact will get added

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
'name'     =>  $subscriberName,
```

because you have undefined variable and post it to then GetResponse API 'name' params without value so GetResponse API return Invalid params.

Change to:

```
$subscriberName => "Some_test_name", // for test only
```

In this line:

```
$subscriberEmail =  $_GET['email'];
```

you should set some email in GET table maybe for test just change to:

```
$subscriberEmail =  "test@domain.com"; // or sth like this.
```

Last idea is var_dump $result variable then you see response from GetResponse API

```
$result = null; // before try {

var_dump($result); // before end of function } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looks good and You have to set the call back url for error handling

Comment: could you be a bit more specific?